# Need to draw a 3D figure based on top, side and front view

Tags: geometry

[image]

Based on the attached image, can someone please help me solve part(d)? I need to draw a 3D figure based on top, side and front view. I have tried it and the closest I could come to was a triangular prism, however one triangular prism does not satisfy the front view.

Comment: I think the answer would be Triangular Prism. The front view doesn't seem to be according to the top and side view. It should be a rectangle with 2 smaller rectangles, instead of 3 as given.

Comment: Could the horizontal lines just be stripes on the surface, and not boundaries between blocks? it is a little unclear.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys, that's exactly whats throwing me off. I saw this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7Rom0HMALo) but cannot seem to get 3 rectangles as per the given front view. Thanks